# Can't add selenium ide extension to webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Any suggestion why the code below is not adding an extension?

```
FirefoxProfile profile1 = new FirefoxProfile();
profile1.AddExtension(@"C:\\Downloads\\selenium-ide-2.5.0.xpi");
IWebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver(profile1);
```

The same code is working fine with firebug add-on. I think there is compatibilty error with the latest firefox. I also tried to install 2.0.0 version of selenium IDE but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was found:

1. Open selenium ide extension as archive (using winrar/winzip/etc)
2. Extract selenium-ide.xpi
3. Add selenium-ide.xpi via addExtension

Result: It works!

Answer (score 0):

It might be help....

```
 File file = new File("firebug-1.8.1.xpi");
 FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
 firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
 firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1"); // Avoid             startup screen
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is solution is for Java vs. C#